# $x^2y''+(3x^2+4x)y'+2(x^2+3x+1)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x^2y''+(3x^2+4x)y'+2(x^2+3x+1)y=0$

I try to solve this equation by finding $\mu$ such that the equation become exact.( I know there are other ways for solving this equation).
$(\mu y')'=\mu'y'+\mu y''=\mu y''+\mu\frac{3x^{2}+4x}{x^{2}}y'+\mu\frac{2(x^{2}+3x+1)}{x^{2}}y \implies$

$\mu'y'=\mu\frac{3x^{2}+4x}{x^{2}}y'+\mu\frac{2(x^{2}+3x+1)}{x^{2}}y \implies \frac{\mu'}{\mu}=\frac{3x^{2}+4x}{x^{2}}+\frac{2(x^{2}+3x+1)}{x^{2}}\frac{y}{y'}$

How am I supposed to solve it?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method to solve equations like this one that uses a clever substitution. The idea is to use substitution to remove the $y'$ term. Whenever you have an equation in the form of $y'' + f(x)y' + g(x)y = 0$, you substitute $y = \exp(-\int f(x)/2\,dx)\mu$. So first, divide through by $x^2$ to get
$$y'' + \underbrace{\frac{3x+4}{x}}_{=f(x)}y' + \underbrace{\frac{2(x^2+3x+1)}{x^2}}_{=g(x)}y = 0.$$
Then substitute in
$$y = \exp\left(-\int \frac{3x+4}{2x}\,dx\right)\mu = \frac{e^{-3x/2}}{x^2}\mu.$$
Doing so (after much simplification) will result in
$$\frac{e^{-3x/2}}{x^2}\mu'' - \frac{e^{-3x/2}}{4x^2}\mu = 0.$$
Divide through by $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-3x/2}}{x^2}$ to get
$$\mu'' - \frac{1}{4}\mu = 0.$$
Using standard methods in ODEs, we get
$$\mu = c_1e^{-x/2} + c_2e^{x/2}.$$
Therefore,
$$y = \frac{e^{-3x/2}}{x^2}\mu = \frac{e^{-3x/2}}{x^2}(c_1e^{-x/2} + c_2e^{x/2}).$$

Comment: +1 that was a beautiful spot

Comment: Thanks! This method work on each second order equation?

Comment: By the way, how can i find $\mu$ such that the equation become exact?